# Unitary representations of free groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, free-groups

I was wondering if there existed finite representations of a free group of rank n? Moreover, I was wondering if there existed unitary representations of free groups of rank n? I am looking to explicitly construct the homomorphism. One idea I had was to obtain a faithful representation by explicitly mapping generators of the free group of rank n, to generators of free subgroups of rank n in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Its not so clear if the same type of argument would hold for $\mathrm{U}_n(\mathbb{C})$, as I am unsure if $\mathrm{U}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a free group of rank n.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A representation of a free group of rank $n$ on $\mathbb C^m$ amounts to an arbitrary $n$-tuple of $m\times m$-matrices. The group $\operatorname{U}_n(\mathbb C)$ is most certainly not free.

Comment: There are plenty of faithful representations of free groups into low-dimensional Lie groups. Indeed, the Tits alternative states that every finitely generated linear group is either virtually solvable or contains a non-abelian free subgroup. With a little thought, it's not too hard to convince oneself that a "generic" pair of elements of $SU(2)$ generate a free group of rank 2.

Comment: @HJRW what is meant by "generic" pair of elements?  Is the choice truly arbitrary? If you could please elaborate on how I could generate such  a subgroup of $SU(2)$, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @HJRW The exceptional subset is a countable union of proper Zariski closed subsets, hence, both meagre and measure zero

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That’s what I had in mind, but I get a bit nervous talking about the Zariski topology on real algebraic varieties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is  another concrete example of a free group in $U_4$.
Let $\cos\theta$ be a transcendental number and let
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 & 0\\
  -\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
  0 & 0 & \sin\theta &  \cos\theta     
\end{pmatrix},\quad
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta & 0\\
  0 & \cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta\\
  -\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta & 0 \\
  0 & -\sin\theta &0 &  \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrices $A$ and $B$ are matrices in the canonical basis $1,i,j,k$ of the following quaternions:
$$
a=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,\quad b=\cos\theta+j\sin\theta.
$$
The group $\operatorname{gr}(A,B)$ is free.

Of course, it is necessary to find $\theta$ such that the number $\cos\theta$ is transcendent.

**Addendum.**

This free group was constructed in 1956 by Th. J. Dekker in Decompositions of sets and spaces II, Indagationes Math. 18, 581-595. In the same paper it is proved that the group $\operatorname{gr}(C,D)$ is also a free group:
$$
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 \\
  -\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},\quad
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 &\\
  0 & \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
  0 & -\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!